# SE2 from Peter Corke's Robotics Toolbox for MATLAB failing

Tags: matlab, robotics

I was trying to follow the MATLAB examples in Peter Corke's *Robotics, Vision and Control* and ran into an error.

`T1` is a transformation matrix obtained from something like:

```
T1 = se2(1,2,30*pi/180)
```

Point `P` is given by:

```
P = [3; 2];
```

First thing I noticed was that `se2` was not recognized in Corke's Robotics Toolbox, but `SE2` was.  The real error, though, occurs when I try to follow the example:

```
P1 = inv(T1) * [P; 1]
```

I get the error:

```
Error using  *  (line 323)
LHS should be matrix with 2 rows
```

I get (I think) that whatever is produced by `SE2` is some structure other than a matrix, but since the whole book of examples is predicated on `SE2`-generated objects being used like matrices, I am kind of stuck.

My MATLAB version is R2018b.

Does anyone have idea/solutions here, or is this a fairly obscure issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting this, I found this solution in a [Google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/robotics-tool-box/SE2$20not$20a$20matrix%7Csort:date/robotics-tool-box/14m8RP7yTV8/cF0_ZUKuAQAJ):

```
P1 = double(inv(T1)) * [P; 1]
```

I'll post the answer here in case it is useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

you should transform the se2 object to a matrix by writing
m=T(T1)
and then u use your matrix as m and T1